# pass values in an array to php variables in Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i design a form and submit it to PHP to process. i put several "input" in this table of form and need to pass them to an array. the "input is not fixed", may be 10 or 20 or more, it can be added or deleted. my question is: i don't know how to pass this "value" to php variable , which in another Multidimensional Arrays
html:

```
1 <input type="text" name="description[]" id="1">
2 <input type="text" name="description[]" id="2">
3 <input type="text" name="description[]" id="3">.....
15 <input type="text" name="description[]" id="15">
```

php:

```
$detail = array ('aa' => 'non','bb' => array('0' => array('Description'=>$_POST['description'][0],'DD'=>'CN'),'1'=>array('Description'=>$_POST['description'][1],'DD'=>'CN')...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand your question what you need is that to push this to the existing array with already have a value:

```
<?php 
 $detail = array('some_existing_value' => 'value1');
 for($i = 0; $i < count($description); $i++) {
     array_push($detail, $description[$i]);
 }
 //then you may try if the value already pushed in arrays
 var_dump($detail);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, if this "detail" is in other Array as the value. how can i do this code?